# Will using AWS Amplify App with both a web and a Flutter app potentially lead to issues if the "amplify push" is executed from one of the frontends?

Tags: reactjs, flutter, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

My main worry is whether running amplify push in the context of my Flutter app might inadvertently affect the configuration of my already-deployed web application. I want to ensure that adding the authentication plugin to the Flutter app won't cause any issues or risks for the web application's configuration.

I have successfully deployed my Amplify application and integrated with web it's up and running smoothly. Now, I'm looking to integrate this Amplify app with a Flutter application. To achieve this, I've already used the amplify pull command to fetch the necessary configurations into my Flutter app's root directory.

Next, I plan to enhance my Flutter app's functionality by incorporating user authentication using cognito. To do this, I intend to execute the amplify add auth command. However, I have concerns about the potential consequences of running amplify push after adding authentication to my Flutter app.